# Animal Crossing-like Mouth Rig?

Tags: modeling, rigging

So I'm starting a new project soon. I'm not sure how to find resources on this, so I'm going to try to describe what I'm going for as clearly as possible.

Essentially, I want to rig an animal model to have its nose wiggle when it talks rather than have a visible moving mouth. Similarly to how [Tom Nook's snout wiggles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQpwx4uSN_o&ab_channel=StormwindGames) when he talks or even [Crazy Redd](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YVsx6EK9kk&ab_channel=MrTobytiger23) from the same series. What would a rig have to look like to achieve this effect?

*Edit: It's kinda subtle here, but I made a little gif to show what I'm talking about.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Wiggle Bone addon could be used for wiggling nose, but it wiggles based on head motion ... In your case nose is moving only at moment of speach ... So just add bone to nose with noise modifier on f-curve and animate just strength like one-off.

Comment: @vklidu sounds like a good idea. i'll give it a shot and post results in a few days